# How to get all open Merge Requests using git command line?

Tags: gitlab, git, github

I need to get all open Merge requests by author and if possible within a time frame. Tried using this command for Github where it works fine -

```
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head'
```

But in gitlab, this is not returning anything, please suggest to get all MRs, if possible status = 'opened', 'closed', 'merged' and time frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the pattern to fetch all Merge Requests from GitLab -

```
git ls-remote origin 'refs/merge-requests/*/head'
```

OR

```
git ls-remote origin 'refs/merge-requests/*/merge'
```